# Table is not mapped error in ninjaframework

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, ninjaframework

I am using ninjaframework for a simple webapp.

I have the following table in mysql:

```
mysql> desc Event;
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| event_id | bigint(20)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| owner_id | bigint(20)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| url1     | varchar(2000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| url2     | varchar(2000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| url3     | varchar(2000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

In My DAO, I have the following code:

```
TypedQuery<Event> query= entityManager.createQuery("SELECT x FROM Event x WHERE event_id = 1", Event.class);
```

This results in the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Event is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3633)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3522)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    ... 43 more
```

I do have an Event class which looks like this:

```
public class Event {
    private int event_id;
    private int owner_id;
    private String url1;
    private String url2;
    private String url3;
    public Event () {
        event_id = -1;
        owner_id = -1;
        url1 = "";
        url2 = "";
        url3 = "";
    }

    public Event(int event_id, int owner_id, String url1, String url2, String url3) {
        this.event_id = event_id;
        this.owner_id = owner_id;
        this.url1 = url1;
        this.url2 = url2;
        this.url3 = url3;
    }
    public int getEventId() {
        return event_id;
    }
    public void setEventId(int id) {
        this.event_id = id;
    }
    public int getOwnerId() {
        return owner_id;
    }
    public void setOwnerId(int id) {
        this.owner_id = id;
    }
    public String getUrl1() {
        return url1;
    }
    public void setUrl1(String url) {
        this.url1 = url;
    }

    public String getUrl2() {
        return url2;
    }
    public void setUrl2(String url) {
        this.url2 = url;
    }

    public String getUrl3() {
        return url3;
    }
    public void setUrl3(String url) {
        this.url3 = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getEventId() + ":" + getUrl1() + ":" + getUrl2() + ":" + getUrl3();
    }
    };
```

Why am I getting this error? Most threads on stackoverflow suggest I should modify hibernate config. But, I do not have any hibernate config file as ninja does not require it.

Comment: Can you please add @Entity(name = "Event") before Event class and import javax.persistence.Entity;

Comment: Can you please accept my answer, so question can be close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please add `@Entity(name = "Event")` before Event class and import javax.persistence.Entity;

```
@Entity(name = "Event")
public class Event {
    private int event_id;
    private int owner_id;
    private String url1;
    private String url2;
    private String url3;
    public Event () {
        event_id = -1;
        owner_id = -1;
        url1 = "";
        url2 = "";
        url3 = "";
    }
```